# how to Fill array with 0 if data is not present?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am working on project where am using chart.js . Using chart.js I have to show chart of monthly profit till current month.
data is coming from server 
   first scenario

```
    data:[0:{month :1 , profit :23}
        1:{month :2 , profit :678}
         .
         .
        0:{month :9 , profit :456}]
```

now i want to fill till 12 month and profit 0 excluding month having profit

second scenario

```
  data:[{0:{month :9 , profit :23}}]
```

here i want to fill array from month 1 to 12 with profit zero excluding the month 9 i.e sep How to do This?

Comment: Have you read the docu or some tutorials? http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

Comment: yes but not getting how to do it new to angular js

Comment: With one google search I found this http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Answer (score 2):

You can play with this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5NpXFa6zP1SMMj0cLldC?p=preview), i think it'll be a great point for starting, you can improve it and adjust it to your needs.

```
 while (i < 12){
    if(data[prev] && i == data[prev][prev].month) {
      array.push(data[prev][prev]);
      prev++;
    } else {
      array.push({i:{month: i, profit: 0}});
  }
i++;
```

}

So that is basically going to be your function so you just have to modify the final array to match the chart.js format, hope this will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adityasharat/09mxoqz1/2/)

Summary:
Basically, sanitize your data. Loop over your data and push whatever data you have into an array. Then loop over an array of 12 (12 months) and put `0` where ever you find a hole in the array.

```
data.forEach(function (item) {
  // -> iterate over all keys in the item
  //    -> for every key get the month and profit and put into result
  //    -> result[month] = profit
});
```

Now fill the holes

```
// create an empty array of size 12
Array.apply(null, {length: 12 }).forEach(function (i, month) {
  // -> if result[month] == null
  //    -> that mean no data for that month is present.
  //    -> put that in the result with profit 0
  //    -> result[month] == 0
});
```

Use `result` array in the chart.